# Residue integral with real as a zero

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Use residues to verify the given
>   integral:$$\text{p.v.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x(x^2+1)^2}dx=\pi(\frac{1}{2}-e^{-2})$$

What I got --  by altering $\sin(2x)$ to its identity $e^{2iz}$ -- is: $$(\pi i+\frac{2\pi i}{e^2})$$ which looks similar to the answer but it is not correct.

Comment: why i think it's an even function?

Comment: @Xiaolang I thought it is even when $f(-z)=f(z)$ which is not the case here?

Comment: sorry i think it in the real analysis,sorry

Comment: @Xiaolang No need to apologize.

Comment: When you finish calculations of the contour integral you should use the identity $e^{2iz}=\cos(2z)+i\sin(2z)$ and compare the real part with the real part and same with the imaginary part which gives you your integral.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I dont think I am following what you said. Will the real part give me $0$? And the imaginary will give me $(\pi +2\pi/e^2)$?

Comment: @Q.matin: Fine, then you should review your derivation. By the way, You should remove the $i$ from your answer.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Why should I remove the $i$?

Comment: @Q.matin Because, $\sin 2x$ is imaginary part of $e^{2iz}$. Imaginary part is the one in front of the $i$, so whenever you get some well formed complex number the coefficient of $i$ is imaginary part, but not $i$ itself, of course.

Comment: Why a principal value integral?

Comment: @Kaster So are you essentially saying if I used this identity $\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$ I would have the correct answer?

Comment: @arbautjc What do you mean?

Comment: @Q.matin, You are asking for a *p.v.* integral, that is, [principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value). This is necessary only for improper integrals, for example when there is a pole and the function isn't integrable. Here the function is $C^\infty$ on $\mathbb{R}$, and the integral is also convergent at $\pm \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is actually

$$2 \pi \left ( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{e^2}\right )$$

which I will show below.

The idea is that you need to split the sine into its exponential components in order to use the semicircular contours in the complex plane.  That is, we consider

$$\oint_C dz \frac{e^{i 2 z}}{z (1+z^2)^2}$$

where $C$ is a semicircular contour in the upper half-plane, except we cut a small semicircular notch above the real axis about the origin in order to avoid the pole on the contour.  In this way, the integral vanishes on the large semicircle as the radius of that semicircle goes to infinity.  (Note that this is why we could not use the sine here, because the $e^{-i 2 z}$ component would diverge here.)  By integrating about the small semicircle at the origin, we get

$$\begin{align}\oint_C dz \frac{e^{i z}}{z (1+z^2)^2} &= PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{i 2 x}}{x (1+x^2)^2} + \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \left[i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \frac{e^{i 2 \epsilon e^{i \phi}}}{\epsilon (1+\epsilon^2 e^{i 2 \phi})^2}\right]\\ &= PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{1 2 x}}{x (1+x^2)^2} - i \pi \end{align}$$

The above is equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues of the poles inside $C$.  In this case, we have a double pole at $z=i$ as the only pole inside $C$.  Thus the residue is

$$\begin{align}\text{Res}_{z=i} &= \lim_{z\rightarrow i}\frac{d}{dz} \left [(z-i)^2\frac{e^{i 2 z}}{z (1+z^2)^2} \right ]\\ &= \frac{d}{dz} \left [\frac{e^{i 2 z}}{z (z+i)^2} \right ]_{z=i}\\ &= \left[\frac{i 2 z (z+i)^2 - (z+i)^2 - 2 z (z+i)}{z^2 (z+i)^4} e^{i 2 z} \right ]_{z=i}\\ &= -\frac{1}{e^2} \end{align}$$

Therefore

$$PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{i 2 x}}{x (1+x^2)^2} = i \pi - \frac{i 2 \pi}{e^2}$$

Now consider

$$\oint_{C'} dz \frac{e^{-i 2 z}}{z (1+z^2)^2}$$

where $C'$ is a semicircular contour in the lower half-plane, with a semicircular notch cut out below the real axis at the origin.  The calculations are very similar to those above and I leave them for the reader.  The result is

$$PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-i 2 x}}{x (1+x^2)^2} = -i \pi + \frac{i 2 \pi}{e^2}$$

Using

$$\sin{2 x} = \frac{e^{i 2 x}-e^{-i 2 x}}{2 i}$$

we subtract the above results and divide by $2 i$/  Note that we can drop the $PV$ from the integrals because the singularities at the origin cancel.  The final result is

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{\sin{2 x}}{x (1+x^2)^2} =  2 \pi \left ( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{e^2}\right )$$

as stated above.

Comment: I had to read this a couple of times to fully understand it, but I do understand it now with your help. Thanks a lot, Ron!